# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure - unable to find login matching

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am getting this issue while publishing my .net core 3.1 app to azure app service.
I am able to publish the application but while hitting a url i am getting this error

Below are error details that i have found out in Event Viewer

> " Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]"

> NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150
> Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.
> [CLIENT: ]

I am also getting this icon when i am trying to publish it
[image]
denoting there are some warning in this section : Dependencies remote.

Other Details:
I am able to run application locally, I have a azure sql database which is connected to this, angular app as frontend and .net core 3.1 app as backend.

I have also tried creating a simple hello world app in .net core 3.1 and tried to deployed it. I am able to publish it and also able to run the url.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: According to your description, the suggestions I gave are based on azure sql server, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> " Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]"

**Judging from your error message, I think that when connecting to azure sql database, it may be filled in some places incorrectly.**

**Generally speaking, as long as the azure sql server can be used, the connection information is correct, and the yellow exclamation mark will not appear when adding Service Dependencies.**

## Troubleshooting steps:

**1. Check login user `NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150`, whether you have the permission to log in to the database.**

（*I think there is a problem with this login user name, please check carefully. In Azure SQL, it is generally not in this format.*）

① Use other tools such as `SSMS` to see if you can log in.

② If not, use the administrator to log in to azure sql server to check if the user name `NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150` is in the user group.

**2. Please check the azure sql server connection information, string, etc. To be consistent with the portal, local user name and password cannot be used, and the login information of azure sql server must be used.**

[image]

[image]